# problems writing out to NetCDF

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

has anyone else encountered this problem with writing to NetCDF? I'm running through a lot of climate model data and producing ensemble means, but for some reason on one model the writing out fails but works on all the others. The data looks fine when I plot it.

```py
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:             (i: 360, j: 300, time: 1032, vertices: 4)
Coordinates:
  * time                (time) datetime64[ns] 2015-01-16T12:00:00 ... 2100-12...
  * j                   (j) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 293 294 295 296 297 298 299
  * i                   (i) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 353 354 355 356 357 358 359
    latitude            (j, i) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(300, 360), meta=np.ndarray>
    longitude           (j, i) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(300, 360), meta=np.ndarray>
Dimensions without coordinates: vertices
Data variables:
    vertices_latitude   (j, i, vertices) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(300, 360, 4), meta=np.ndarray>
    vertices_longitude  (j, i, vertices) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(300, 360, 4), meta=np.ndarray>
    sithick             (time, j, i) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1032, 300, 360), meta=np.ndarray>
```

```py
ds_emean.to_netcdf(path=file_out,mode='w',format='NETCDF4',compute=True)
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.12.0) thread 123145549598720:
  #000: H5Dio.c line 192 in H5Dread(): can't read data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Read failed
  #001: H5VLcallback.c line 2080 in H5VL_dataset_read(): dataset read failed
    major: Virtual Object Layer
    minor: Read failed
  #002: H5VLcallback.c line 2046 in H5VL__dataset_read(): dataset read failed
    major: Virtual Object Layer
    minor: Read failed
  #003: H5VLnative_dataset.c line 167 in H5VL__native_dataset_read(): can't read data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Read failed
  #004: H5Dio.c line 567 in H5D__read(): can't read data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Read failed
  #005: H5Dchunk.c line 2594 in H5D__chunk_read(): unable to read raw data chunk
    major: Low-level I/O
    minor: Read failed
  #006: H5Dchunk.c line 3957 in H5D__chunk_lock(): data pipeline read failed
    major: Dataset
    minor: Filter operation failed
  #007: H5Z.c line 1336 in H5Z_pipeline(): filter returned failure during read
    major: Data filters
    minor: Read failed
  #008: H5Zdeflate.c line 123 in H5Z_filter_deflate(): inflate() failed
    major: Data filters
    minor: Unable to initialize object
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: hi there! welcome to stack overflow. please read the guide to [ask] and make sure to check out the help guide to [formatting](/help/formatting). also, please always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) (the bit *including and below* `Traceback (most recent call last):`) when asking about errors. Thanks!

Comment: it looks like you're getting errors on read. did you plot all the data or just a subset?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to plot the data just fine, I'm just having trouble to save it. It's only for one particular climate model that I'm having the problem but it is strange as I'm doing the same statement for all of them

Comment: strange. it just looks like you're running into trouble reading one of the chunks. I'd try subsetting the data to see if you can identify which block the error occurs for. I'd think you should get this error for any read error including the offending chunk(s) -  something like `ds.mean().compute()` should raise this. it's possible you'll need to re-download/re-create the file you're reading.